# Rewrite javascript function with selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I need to rewrite a existing function which is created by the website when the page is loaded. The function is something like this:

```
function CheckStatus() {
    var vcode = $.trim($("#insertCode").val()).toUpperCase();
    var vreturn = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('text_return').value);
... (lots of other stuff)
}
```

And I would like to rewite this function to be like this:

```
function CheckStatus() {
 return true;
}
```

If I paste this function in the chrome console, it rewrites with no problem. But when I try to do it with selenium It does not rewrite... I think it creates another function with the same name. My code in python using selenium webdriver is this:

```
driver.execute_script("function CheckStatus() { return true;}")
```

It does not return errors. Nothing happens actually.

Any clues how to solve this with selenium?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solve it with something similar:

```
driver.execute_script("CheckStatus = function CheckStatus() { return true;}")
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a *function declaration*. Nothing is executed here because you didn't ask to execute anything, you just defined a function. What you want looks more like this:

```
driver.execute_script("() => ({ return true;})()")
```

Don't forget to actually **call you function** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure, but try to set the function to **window** object, maybe python's selenium has another name space

so:

```
driver.execute_script("window.CheckStatus = () => true;")
```